# Spark Structured Stream - Kinesis as Data Source

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, spark-structured-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to consume kinesis data stream records using psypark structured stream.
I am trying to run this code in aws glue batch job. My goal is to use checkpoint and save checkpoints and data to s3. I am able to consume the data but it is giving only few records for every trigger whereas kinesis data stream has lot of records. I am using TRIM_HORIZON which is alias to earliest and trigger spark.writestream once so that it executes once and shuts down the cluster. When i run the job again, it picks latest offset from checkpoint and runs.

```
kinesis = spark.readStream.format('kinesis') \
        .option('streamName', kinesis_stream_name) \
        .option('endpointUrl', 'blaablaa')\
        .option('region', region) \
        .option('startingPosition', 'TRIM_HORIZON')\
        .option('maxOffsetsPerTrigger',100000)\
        .load()
```

// do some transformation here

```
TargetKinesisData = stream_data.writeStream.format("parquet").outputMode('append').option(
        "path", s3_target).option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location).trigger(once=True).start().awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

The spark checkpoint location parameter stores information about previous records it processed successfully. So when same records come again it does not process them. If you change/delete the checkpoint location and re-run the job it will consume all the data in your stream.

**Details**

When writing spark streaming jobs there are two options which decide what data will be read when a streaming job is restarted.

1. Starting Position Parameter : This parameter will fetch the results from AWS Kinesis based on the parameters shared i.e. earliest, latest or based on timestamp. read the following [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_StartingPosition.html) for usage.
2. Spark Stream Checkpoint: This parameter stores information about which records were successfully processed and this helps to provide consistency and avoid re-reading the old records. Read [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#fault-tolerance-semantics) about spark streaming fault tolerance